# Standard Logic App fails to connect to storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which is linked to a storage account to store workflow state, run history, and artifacts. After we set the public network access of storage account to "*Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses*", Logic app fails. Added all the firewall rules and enabled "*Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account*." exception.

What am I still missing here?

Note :  Logic app does not directly connect to storage account using any connectors

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you need to create a private endpoint for that storage account and integrate it with Vnet :

[image]

[image]

Then you can open your Logic apps in a Virtual Machine( VM integrated with same Vnet as Storage account)

If you run your Logic app in that VM then you can get the desired results as below:

[image]

Comment: Do we have any other option instead of creating private endpoint? The reason is because these apps have been built long back and making any changes would take time and we need to fix this asap.

Comment: AFAIK, only this one